# MATLAB default line color

Tags: matlab, colors, line

How can I set the line color of all plots in MATLAB? Something like:

```
set(0,'DefaultLineColor','k');
```

Also what is the meaning of `0` in the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
set(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',[0 0 0]);
```

Put it at the beginning of your script or your matlab start file. `0` just means that you are setting default values. [Here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/creating_plots/setting-default-property-values.html) you can find more on default values.